# constrexpr constructor inherited from shared_ptr

Tags: c++, memory, constructor, shared-ptr, constexpr

I want to implement my own pointer (with few helper methods) extended from shared_ptr.

```
class Event;

class EventPtr : public std::shared_ptr<Event> {
public:
    constexpr EventPtr()
        : std::shared_ptr<Event>() {
    }

    constexpr EventPtr(std::nullptr_t p)
        : std::shared_ptr<Event>(p) {
    }

    explicit EventPtr(Event* ptr)
        : std::shared_ptr<Event>(ptr) {
    }
};
```

The problem is that compiler gives me the following error for both constexpr constructors: 
*constexpr constructor never produces constant expression*

Tell me please how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry for posting an incorrect answer (noise). I just didn't see the relevant constructor in the list over at cppreference, instead I saw a templated one. I have deleted the answer.

Comment: the link is here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules on constexpr constructors changed between C++11 and C++14; see [DR1911 *constexpr constructor with non-literal base class*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1911) and [this bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19344).

The fix is to compile in C++14 mode (`-std=c++14`).

Language in C++11 **[dcl.constexpr]**:

> For a constexpr function, if no function argument values exist such that the function invocation substitution would produce a constant expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required. For a constexpr constructor, if no argument values exist such that after function invocation substitution, every
>   constructor call and full-expression in the mem-initializers would be a constant expression (including conversions), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Under C++11, `shared_ptr` can have `constexpr` constructors but any class type inheriting from `shared_ptr` or with a `shared_ptr` member cannot, because `shared_ptr` is not a literal type (it has a destructor) and so cannot appear in a constant expression. For C++14 this was simplified to:

> For a non-template, non-defaulted constexpr function or a non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting constexpr constructor, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (5.19), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Unfortunately this makes *all* constexpr constructors of non-literal types undefined behavior; DR1911 fixed this by adding a subclause (**bolded** below):

> For a non-template, non-defaulted constexpr function or a non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting constexpr constructor, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (5.20), **or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object (3.6.2),** the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

```
struct X { ~X() {} constexpr X() {} };   // OK in C++11, UB in C++14, OK since DR1911
struct Y : X { constexpr Y() : X() {} }; // UB in C++11, UB in C++14, OK since DR1911
```

Comment: I don't see how this applies (and, 2nd, is the emphasized passage new to C++14 or removed in C++14)? Since both used `shared_ptr` constructors are `constexpr`, why can an invocation be "an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression"? What are those constructors that have that property then?

Comment: "why can't", not "why can".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks, I got confused by the text of DR1911. C++11 permits constexpr constructors of non-literal types but not of types inheriting from or containing non-literal types; C++14 actually makes all constexpr constructors of non-literal types UB, but the DR fixes this.

Comment: @ecatmur sorry, what is UB?

Comment: @Peregrin UB is [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).